# LISP to Batchplot (Publish) Multiple .dwg Models into One PDF

Tags: lisp, publish, autocad

I've been tasked with the objective of creating a LISP which will automatically batchplot (publish) all Models in a set of .dwg in a given folder to a single .pdf. The idea is that we will create a routine which will run this LISP once a week to keep the .pdf, which is used by non-CAD users, up to date.

I am new to LISP but as I've tried to plan this out, I've come up with the idea that I would create a temp .dsd file based on the .dwg filename containing a substring of characters (ex. KER) and load that .dsd into PUBLISH command. Each Model would be passed the same page setup.

Does this sound feasible? Does anyone have any experience doing something similar and can provide some examples?